# Facing an issue while sending a group of checkboxes into database using php,Mysqli

Tags: error-handling

My requirement is supposed there are 3 group of checkboxes each group containing 5 checkboxes a user either check all groups or can leave one group I am facing an issue here Everything is perfect if the user checks all groups if he leaves a group unchecked.. I am getting an error like this

```
Undefined index: projectstatus in C:\wamp\www\bis\formpage.php on line 19
implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\bis\formpage.php on line 20
```

I have searched many sources but I cant fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors mean that the `projectstatus` was not posted.  If a checkbox is not checked, then it will not be in the $_POST at all. 
To prevent the errors, in the script you are posting to, you can first test to see if projectstatus is there before attempting to do anything with it.
You can wrap everything in an if statement like `if(array_key_exists('projectstatus',$_POST) ) { }`